# Android: how to change menu item at page scrolling with ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, menuitem, swipe-gesture

The last version of WhatsApp does what I'm talking about. When you scroll between tabs the toolbar shows different menu options. I can implement ViewPager with adapter and fragments but not this. How could it be done? I really don't know what kind of trick is behind. It changes everytime you switch pages

Comment: you have to override `onCreateOptionsMenu` on each fragment

Comment: it's not something only activity can do?

Comment: no it is not. Fragment has also this possibility. Don't forget to call `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in onCreate of your Fragment

Comment: I don't get it, please, can you show me an example with an answers? I tried but it's not overridable

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In each Fragment you have to override `onCreateOptionsMenu`, with different `menu/menu.xml` files

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Don't forget to call `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`, in onCreate of your `Fragment`

Comment: @Blackbelt can you tell me how can we make the options menu be the same in all across the view pager fragments but only tool bar menu change like in whatsApp, currently both menu are same ...